# Better way to "wrap all" elements as their own divs with unique class names?

Tags: jquery

I am simply trying to grab some specific elements on a page and wrap them all in their own unique divs.

As you can see each element is wrapped in its own wrapper  and has a unique class. I am using Jquery. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this? It works its just.. bulky..

Thanks for any help!

```
$('#post-178439 .duplicate').wrapAll('<div class="diamondLinkWrapper1" />');
$('#post-178443 .duplicate').wrapAll('<div class="diamondLinkWrapper2" />');
$('#post-178395 .duplicate').wrapAll('<div class="diamondLinkWrapper3" />');
$('#post-178447 .duplicate').wrapAll('<div class="diamondLinkWrapper4" />');
$('#post-178451 .duplicate').wrapAll('<div class="diamondLinkWrapper5" />');
$('#post-178455 .duplicate').wrapAll('<div class="diamondLinkWrapper6" />');
$('#post-178431 .duplicate').wrapAll('<div class="diamondLinkWrapper7" />');
$('#post-178435 .duplicate').wrapAll('<div class="diamondLinkWrapper8" />');
```

Comment: Do you want to do this for all the elements having id like `post-*` or only for the above mentioned specific ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mlIds = [178439, 178443, 178395, 178447, 178451, 178455, 178431, 178435];

for(var i=0; i<mlIds.length; i++) {
    $('#post-' + mlIds[i] + ' .duplicate').wrapAll('<div class="diamondLinkWrapper'+ i +'"/>');
}
```

Try this...
put your ids in an array and use for loop, also apply each index to your class

Answer (score 0):

You need to gather all of the divs you want to change, and loop through them:

```
var divs = $('[id^="post-"]').find('.duplicate');
console.log(divs);
var counter = 1;
$.each(divs, function(){
    $(this).wrap('<div class="diamondLinkWrapper' + counter + '" />');
    counter++;
});
```

Here's a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/cjk8k7bw/1/

```js
  var divs = $('[id^="post-"]').find('.duplicate');
  console.log(divs);
  var counter = 1;
  $.each(divs, function(){
      $(this).wrap('<div class="diamondLinkWrapper' + counter + '" />');
      counter++;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="post-1234"><div class="duplicate">content</div></div>
<div id="post-2345"><div class="duplicate">content</div></div>
<div id="post-3456"><div class="duplicate">content</div></div>
<div id="post-4567"><div class="duplicate">content</div></div>
<div id="post-5678"><div class="duplicate">content</div></div>
<div id="post-6789"><div class="duplicate">content</div></div>
<div id="post-7890"><div class="duplicate">content</div></div>
<div id="post-8901"><div class="duplicate">content</div></div>
<div id="post-9101"><div class="duplicate">content</div></div>
<div id="post-1011"><div class="duplicate">content</div></div>
<div id="post-1213"><div class="duplicate">content</div></div>
<div id="post-1314"><div class="duplicate">content</div></div>
<div id="post-1516"><div class="duplicate">content</div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is to use a for loop. For my example I have set the loop number to 8 as that is the number of lines you provided above.

```
for(var i=0; i<=8; i++){
    $('#post-178439 .duplicate').wrapAll('<div class="diamondLinkWrapper'+i +'"/>');
}
```

If you need a higher number, then change the second parameter of the for loop to what ever number you need.